# Parse Date From an Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am consuming a Rest API and the return of one of the data is a datetime that is return in an Array. Exactly like this:

```
"beginDate": [2018, 7, 24, 8, 22, 0, 0]
```

In my rails app I want to parse this data into a date time format. I already try this way:

```
Date.new(object["beginDate"].join)
```

And this way:

```
Date.parse(object["beginDate"].join)
```

Also this:

```
DateTime.new(object["beginDate"].join)
DateTime.parse(object["beginDate"].join)
```

Every code return an error like: 'Invalid date'.

How can I parse the data in to a datetime format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a `DateTime` object, not a `Date` in the first place. [`DateTime#new`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-new) accepts seven arguments, hence all you need is to splat an array you have:

```
DateTime.new(*object["beginDate"])
```

Comment: Thanks, for trying to help. I already had try with the DateTime.new, with out the *, as a put above and didn't work. With the * before it work, what that symbol does?

Comment: Here it allows the array to be passed as the list of parameters. Here is a [good writing](https://medium.com/@sarahalder/ruby-s-splat-operator-1edaaad83268) or just google “ruby splat operator.”

Comment: Thanks, It helps me alot.